# WPF Prism and Ribbon

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have two modules. Each module has a ribbon tab. I want to load both modules on application startup and switch them depending on the ribbon tab the user has selected. Is it possible?
I see only first registered Module "MonteuranforderungModule".

[App screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT4U0.png)

**App.xaml.cs**

```
using KDForms.Core.Regions;
using Monteuranforderung;
using Abholschein;
using KDForms.Views;
using Prism.Ioc;
using Prism.Modularity;
using Prism.Regions;
using Prism.Unity;
using System.Windows;
using Monteuranforderung.Views;

namespace KDForms
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
        protected override Window CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell(Window shell)
        {
            base.InitializeShell(shell);
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            
        }

        protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog)
        {
            moduleCatalog.AddModule<MonteuranforderungModule>();
            moduleCatalog.AddModule<AbholscheinModule>();
        }

        protected override void ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings(RegionAdapterMappings regionAdapterMappings)
        {
            base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings(regionAdapterMappings);
            regionAdapterMappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(Fluent.Ribbon), Container.Resolve<FluentRibbonRegionAdapter>());
        }

        protected override void ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors(IRegionBehaviorFactory regionBehaviors)
        {
            base.ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors(regionBehaviors);

            regionBehaviors.AddIfMissing(DependentViewRegionBehavior.BehaviorKey, typeof(DependentViewRegionBehavior));
        }
```

I tried load Modules with config file. In the end, the same

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="modules" type="Prism.Modularity.ModulesConfigurationSection, Prism.Wpf"/>
    </configSections>

    <modules>
        <module assemblyFile="Monteuranforderung.dll" moduleType="Monteuranforderung.MonteuranforderungModule, Monteuranforderung, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"  moduleName="Monteuranforderung" startupLoaded="true" />
        <module assemblyFile="Abholschein.dll" moduleType="Abholschein.AbholscheinModule, Abholschein, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"  moduleName="Abholschein" startupLoaded="true"/>
    </modules>
</configuration>
```

here is **FluentRibbonRegionAdapter**

```
using Fluent;
using Prism.Regions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace KDForms.Core.Regions
{
    public class FluentRibbonRegionAdapter : RegionAdapterBase<Ribbon>
    {
        public FluentRibbonRegionAdapter(IRegionBehaviorFactory regionBehaviorFactory)
            : base(regionBehaviorFactory)
        {
        }

        protected override void Adapt(IRegion region, Ribbon regionTarget)
        {
            if (region == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(region));
            if (regionTarget == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(regionTarget));

            region.Views.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                {
                    foreach (var view in e.NewItems)
                    {
                        AddViewToRegion(view, regionTarget);
                    }

                }
                else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
                {
                    foreach (var view in e.OldItems)
                    {
                        RemoveViewFromRegion(view, regionTarget);
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        protected override IRegion CreateRegion()
        {
            return new SingleActiveRegion();
        }

        static void AddViewToRegion(object view, Ribbon FluentRibbon)
        {
            if (view is RibbonTabItem ribbonTabItem)
            {
                FluentRibbon.Tabs.Add(ribbonTabItem);
            }
        }

        static void RemoveViewFromRegion(object view, Ribbon FluentRibbon)
        {
            if (view is RibbonTabItem ribbonTabItem)
            {
                FluentRibbon.Tabs.Remove(ribbonTabItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's `FluentRibbonRegionAdapter` from? The whole logic's supposed to be in there.

Comment: `SingleActiveRegion` deactivates all views but one, to see more than one tab you need `AllActiveRegion`. Plus some logic to navigate the content region when switching ribbon the tabs.